# How to print Lists side by side with Flask

Tags: python

I posted this recently, but am submitting another question with updated code (please let me know if I shouldn't do this)

I am wondering how to print two lists of the same size next to each other.

I have got these lists from a nested dict.

Here are the lists:

```
[
  [
    "Chelsea", 
    "Liverpool", 
    "ManCity", 
    "Arsenal", 
    "Spurs", 
    "ManU", 
    "Southampton", 
    "West Bromwich", 
    "Everton", 
    "Bournemouth", 
    "Stoke", 
    "Watford", 
    "West Ham", 
    "Middlesbrough", 
    "Foxes", 
    "Burnley", 
    "Crystal", 
    "Sunderland", 
    "Swans", 
    "Hull"
  ], 
  [
    43, 
    37, 
    36, 
    34, 
    33, 
    30, 
    24, 
    23, 
    23, 
    21, 
    21, 
    21, 
    19, 
    18, 
    17, 
    17, 
    15, 
    14, 
    12, 
    12
  ]
]
```

Essentially, I want the list to be:

Chelsea: 44 Liverpool:37

etc...

Here is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import httplib
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index1():
    return render_template('league.html')

@app.route('/League Standing', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_league():
    text = request.form['league']
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
    headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'key', 'X-Response-Control': 'minified'}
    connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions/'+text+'/leagueTable', None, headers)
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
    teamnames = [r['team'] for r in response['standing']]
    points = [r['points'] for r in response['standing']]
    for teamnames, points in zip(response):
        print('{}: {}'.format(teamnames, points))
    #return jsonify(teamnames, points)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I honestly don't care about the format of the code right now - I will fix this when it's working!

I have tried to:

```
zip(teamname, points)
```

to no avail!

Please help!

EDIT:

```
for t, p in zip(teamnames, points):
    return '{}: {}'.format(t,p)
```

This code returns jsut the first team!

Answer (score 0):

Completely different direction, but why don't you try::

```
results = [{'team': r['team'], 'points': r['points']} for r in response['standing']]

for r in results:
    print "{team}: {points}".format(r)
```

Comment: then what happens to teamname and points?

Comment: the two variables after `for` are used to unpack the tuple from the zip function. in your code above i think the issue is you can't unpack lists with the same name into variables with the same name. you're code is a bit confusing some i'm not 100% sure i understand your question.

Comment: essentially I am trying to print the list: teamname next to points

Comment: OK - i misunderstood. Updating

Comment: TY. I want it to print as 

Chelsea: 44

Comment: Cool...hope you have it working now!

Comment: I do not have it yet.

Comment: This update did not work either.

Comment: Are you positive your query is returning what you expect? e.g. maybe add a `print response` line to debug. all these variations have worked for me directly in the python console